# Problem Setting Up AJAX Request in Wordpress (with JQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am getting an error of "500 (Internal Server Error). I have gone through a lot of the solutions here and they don't seem to change my outcome and I'm not sure why. I am still learning `Wordpress` and `Ajax` so any help is appreciated!

My `functions.php`:

```
<?php
// register and enqueue custom js scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hyix_enqueue_custom_js');
function hyix_enqueue_custom_js() {
    //enqueue zip-search-popup.js
    wp_enqueue_script('zip-search-popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/zip-search-popup.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_localize_script('zip-search-popup', 'from_php', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
} 
//hook zip-search function into ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_zip_search', 'zip_search' );
//same hook for users not logged in
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'zip_search' );

//query for pulling in shipping data
function zip_search() {
  $submittedZip = $_REQUEST['submittedZip'];
  global $wpdb;
  // The SQL query
  $response  =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_name ".
              "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
              "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
              "ON {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id ".
              "WHERE location_code = '$submittedZip' ");
  $response = array(
    'request' => $_REQUEST,
    'zip' => $submittedZip,
    'test' => 'is ok',
  );
  wp_send_json( $response );
  // echo $response;
  die();
}
```

My jQuery file - `zip-search-popup.js`:

```
  (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.zip-bar-button').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          submittedZip = $("#zipcode-bar-input").val();
          console.log(submittedZip);
          $.ajax({
            url: from_php.ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              action : 'zip_search',
              submittedZip : submittedZip,
            },
            success: function (response) {
              console.log("this is the response: " + response);
              alert("working");
            },
          })
        })
      })
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is you ajax url getting called ?

Comment: Do you mean with this?
 $.ajax({
            url: from_php.ajax_url,

Comment: Yes............

Comment: It's in the code. I'm confused about what you are asking? Are you saying did I check if it is actually being called? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Check the browser network console to see if any request is being called via `ajax` on a button click. ALso how do you know its 500 error ? where you see it ?

Comment: I see the following:
Name: admin-ajax.php
Status: 500
Type: XHR
Initiator: Jquery (with version number information)

I am assuming this means that Ajax was called since it is referencing the WP admin-ajax.php file, correct?

Comment: I can not see anything in your code i have tested this on my localHost and it works fine.

Comment: That in itself is very helpful. At least I will stop beating my head over the setup, it must be something outside of it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, the button is part of a form that is in my home.html file.

Comment: I have heard this place is super harsh sometimes. It wasn't me... I don't even have enough rep for my votes to count unfortunately :( I am going to test it in the morning and will mark it as the answer... not sure if that does anything.

Comment: I know its not you :)  The code i posted works perfectly on my localHost and should just fine for you as well. No problem - please test it and it mark it as answer by clicking the grey checkmark in my answer - Let me know if i help further.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked like a charm! I am going through it now to better understand what I missed.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Let me know if i can help any further :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working `code` for you you need to add this `code` in your `child-theme` `functions.php`
I have made few **changes** to the code the way you `wp_enqueue_scripts` in wordpress.

**child-theme (functions.php)**

```
function my_custom_scripts() {

    $myvars = array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) //admin ajax
    );
  
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/zip-search-popup.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', $myvars );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );

//hook zip-search function into ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_zip_search', 'zip_search' );
//same hook for users not logged in
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'zip_search' );

//query for pulling in shipping data
function zip_search() {
  $submittedZip = $_REQUEST['submittedZip'];
  global $wpdb;

  //The SQL query
  $response  =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_name ".
              "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
              "INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
              "ON {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id ".
              "WHERE location_code = '$submittedZip' ");
  $response = array(
    'request' => $_REQUEST,
    'zip' => $submittedZip,
    'test' => 'is ok',
  );
  wp_send_json( $response );
}
```

**child theme (js file - jQuery code)** zip-search-popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.zip-bar-button').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        submittedZip = $("#zipcode-bar-input").val();
        console.log(submittedZip);
        $.ajax({
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                action: 'zip_search',
                submittedZip: submittedZip,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("this is the response: " + response);
                alert("working");
            },
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is going wrong, check the error.log of your php server..?